# How to get supervisorctl status of processes?

Tags: php, linux

I have supervisorctl running with about 50 processes. Now I want to get the status of these processes on my website. My idea is to use on php exec(“sudo supervisorctl status”) and set the output to a array or something like that. I only need the first 2 colons.

```
process1                         RUNNING    pid 935, uptime 17386 days, 14:52:25
process2                         RUNNING    pid 936, uptime 17386 days, 14:52:25
process3                         RUNNING    pid 31907, uptime 0:00:09
```

What is the best way to do this.

Comment: You mean the two colons in `14:52:25`?

Comment: You can use a regular expression to extract the first two fields in the outpu. Or you could use `supervisorctl status | awk '{print $1, $2}'`

Comment: Thanks, supervisorctl status | awk '{print $1, $2}' was the solution. I have now exec("sudo supervisorctl status | awk '{print $1, $2}'", $output); And on $output I have the array that I want.

Comment: `sudo supervisorctl status | awk '{print $1, $2}'` showed me that 8 Laravel workers are running.  https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queues#supervisor-configuration

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? If this is really a PHP problem, share the code that you are using

Answer (score 9):

You can use a regular expression to extract the first two fields in the outpu. Or you could use `supervisorctl status | awk '{print $1, $2}'`

Credits to [@Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of parsing the text output from the `supervisorctl` command, you could talk directly to the `supervisord` process using [XML-RPC](http://xmlrpc.com/). The supervisor documentation includes the [supported API calls](http://supervisord.org/api.html).

It's easiest if you configure the daemon to listen on a [local HTTP server](http://supervisord.org/configuration.html#inet-http-server-section-settings); let's assume you configured it to listen on the default port 9001 on localhost, so you can connect over HTTP to localhost:9001. PHP has built-in support for XML-RPC but you do need to [enable the feature](https://www.php.net/manual/en/xmlrpc.installation.php). If you installed PHP using your system's package manager, look for a `php-xmlrpc` package to install. Alternatively, install a pure PHP XML-RPC package like [polyfill-xmlrpc](https://github.com/gggeek/polyfill-xmlrpc).

To get the status of all managed processes, use the [`supervisor.getAllProcessInfo()` method](http://supervisord.org/api.html#supervisor.rpcinterface.SupervisorNamespaceRPCInterface.getAllProcessInfo); this returns an array of processes, and you'll need the `name` and `statename` columns from those:

```php
define('SUPERVISOR_RPC_URL', 'http://localhost:9001/RPC2');

function supervisor_states() {
    $request = xmlrpc_encode_request("supervisor.getAllProcessInfo", array());
    $context = stream_context_create(['http' => [
        'method' => "POST",
        'header' => "Content-Type: text/xml",
        'content' => $request
    ]]);
    $file = file_get_contents(SUPERVISOR_RPC_URL, false, $context);
    $response = xmlrpc_decode($file);
    if (is_array($response) && xmlrpc_is_fault($response)) {
        // Consider creating a custom exception class for this.
        throw new Exception($response['faultString'], $response['faultCode']);
    }
    return array_map(
        function($proc) {
            return ['name'=>$proc['name'], 'status'=>$proc['statusname']];
        },
        $response,
    );
}
```

This returns an multidimensional array with `name` and `status` keys. The latter is the process state, see the [*Process States* documentation](http://supervisord.org/subprocess.html#process-states) for possible values.